# First version of strong law / $\lim a_n^4 = 0 \to \lim a_n = 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

From Williams' Probability w/ Martingales:

[image]

[image]

How does the conclusion follow?

Guess 1:

$E[\sum (\frac{S_n}{n})^4] < \infty$

$\to \sum (\frac{S_n}{n})^4 < \infty$ a.s.

$\to \lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{S_n}{n})^4 = 0$ a.s.

$\to \lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{S_n}{n}) = 0$ a.s.?

So $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n^4 = 0 \to \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ ?

Guess 2:

$E[\sum (\frac{S_n}{n})^4] < \infty$

$\to E[\sum (\frac{S_n}{n})] < \infty$

$\to \sum (\frac{S_n}{n}) < \infty$ a.s.

$\to \lim (\frac{S_n}{n}) = 0$ a.s.

Any of those right? If not, how else can I approach this?

Comment: If the expectation of a r.v. is finite, then that random variable must be a.s. finite. In this particular case, the random variable whose expectation is finite (and hence is a.s. finite) is itself an infinite series, and since the terms of a convergent series must approach zero, the result follows. So Guess 1 would be the correct one. Guess 2 is totally incorrect.

Comment: Of course it is true that if $a_n^4 \to 0$ then $a_n \to 0$. The fourth root function is continuous. A direct proof with epsilons is also easy.

Comment: @Shalop Thanks! Just realised $E[X^4] < \infty \to E[X] < \infty$ is not applicable. Post as answer?

Comment: The statement "$E[X^4]<\infty \implies E[|X|]< \infty$" is actually true. What is NOT true is that $\sum (S_n/n)^4 = \big(\sum S_n/n \big)^4 $, and **that** is the reason why the first implication in Guess 2 fails. Sorry, I'm too lazy to post an actual answer.

Comment: @Shalop No need for apologies. Just wanted to give rep as a thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Shalop's comments:

Guess 1 is correct because $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n^4 = (\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n)^4$ because $f(x) = x^4$ is continuous.

Guess 2 is wrong: While $E[X^4] < \infty \to E[|X|] < \infty \to E[X] < \infty$ is true, it is not applicable.

Guess 2 mixes up $\sum (\frac{S_n}{n})^4$ and $(\sum \frac{S_n}{n})^4$

Comment: What is this new fad of deleting your answer to your own question and reposting it soon afterwards nearly identical? Ever heard of the possibility of *editing* your answer?

Comment: Did has a point here. This is strange behavior. Are you aware of the fact that 10k+ users can see deleted posts? I try not to make judgement here, but I give you this friendly piece of advice. Having duplicate posts listed with your name leaves an unfavorable impression. This may lead to other problems. For example it erodes the legitimacy of your complaints about the behavior of others when you follow the modus operandi of "a downvote => delete, repost and hope for better luck next time"

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Even if the downvote is unjustified or unexplained? I mean really, I just wanted this question to be answered. Shalop is the one who didn't want to post as answer. Then all of a sudden my answer gets downvoted. Thanks for the friendly advice, but what am I to do about the (unjustified or unexplained) downvotes then?

Comment: The voters have no obligation to justify their decision. Be it upvote or a donvote. Too many users retaliate explained downvotes for it to become the norm to explain them.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ayt thanks then